# Efficient way to aggregate two dictionaries?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, aggregation

I have two dictionaries:

```
a = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4}
b = {a:10, b:20, c:30, e:50}
```

I want to merge to merge these two dictionaries in way of aggregating the common key by summation of values and get something like:

```
merged = {a:11, b:22, c:33, d:4, e:50}
```

One possible way might be conversing both `dict`s to pandas `dataframe` the use `group-by()` and then convert back the result into a `dict`. However, I am wondering if there is any more efficient way to do that?